# Bind9 how stop to answer specific queries?

Tags: bind, query

How I can make Bind9 to stop answering specific types of queries, let say NULL, WKS or TXT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The "blackhole" facilities of BIND 9 are extremely limited (a fact that's been exploited for a variety of back-scatter attacks). If you're running Linux you can configure IP Tables to drop packets with those types of requests. [A vaguely similar Q&A has some good information in it.](https://serverfault.com/questions/438515/bind-blackhole-for-invalid-recursive-queries)

Comment: Thanks, too bad for that :( I just noticed that Yourfreedom uses this for make a transparent proxy.