# Setup DNS Forward Server to forward only specific domains

Tags: bind, internal-dns, dns-zone, forwarding, dns-hosting

I want to setup DNS Forwarding Server to forward DNS resolution requests for only specific zones.

I am using the following config.

```
acl "trusted" {
        localhost;
        10.x.x.x/24;
};

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 10.x.x.x; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";

        allow-query     { trusted; };

        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
};

zone "forward.example.com" {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 10.x.x.x; };
};
```

This is forwarding `forward.example.com` to correct DNS, but it also resolves other URLs.
I want DNS Server to forward only for `forward.example.com` and return nothing for others, so that client uses it's own fallback DNS.

Comment: I would say that simply dropping the query so that the secondary servers handle the request is not the best way to do it. You can have the server forward other queries to another specific server, so it can benefit from that server's cache, etc. However, if you are really tied to this idea of silently dropping the query, you may want to read through [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/438515)